# Watch Face isn't recognised as a standalone app by Google Play store

Tags: google-play, wear-os, google-play-console, watch-face-api

I am developing a watch face using the Watch Face Format. My watch face consists of a Wear OS bundle (the watch face itself) and an optional companion app for the mobile phone.

I have set my watch face to be a standalone app (following the instructions from the https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps) by setting the `com.google.android.wearable.standalone` meta data in the manifest.xml:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
        android:hasCode="false">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <property
            android:name="com.google.wear.watchface.format.version"
            android:value="1" />

    </application>
```

However, for some reason Google Play still thinks that the Wear OS bundle is a non-standalone app (see the "Requires mobile app" message in the screenshot below).

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Do you guys have any ideas what could be wrong?

[image]